# why need in Locate plugin find section the following line?

Tags: nsis

```
Section
    ${Locate} "C:\ftp" "/L=F /M=RPC DCOM.rar /S=1K" "Example1"
    ; 'RPC DCOM.rar' file in 'C:\ftp' with size 1 Kb or more

    IfErrors 0 +2
    MessageBox MB_OK "Error" IDOK +2
    MessageBox MB_OK "$$R0=$R0"
SectionEnd

Function Example1
    StrCpy $R0 $R9
    ; $R0="C:\ftp\files\RPC DCOM.rar"

    MessageBox MB_YESNO '$R0$\n$\nFind next?' IDYES +2
    ** StrCpy $0 StopLocate ** -> why needs this line? 

    Push $0
FunctionEnd
```

Thx for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${Locate}` has a loop that looks for files that matches your input and when it finds one it calls your callback-function (Example1 in this case). It searches subdirectories by default so there could be more than one "RPC DCOM.rar" file.

If you only care about the first file then you can stop it from searching other subdirectories by `push`ing the string "StopLocate" to the stack. `Push`ing anything else will continue the search...

Comment: Thank you!
May be you know how to write iferrors for Zipdll plugin.
ZipDLL::extractall "c:\test.zip" "c:\output"
wehen example you dont have enough space, or havent got permission...so zipdll has exit code or something?

Comment: You should not ask unrelated questions in comments. All I can say about ZipDLL is to read the documentation it has, I have never used it so I don't know.